# Как перевернуть массив в Джаве?

Tags: java

[image: Код]

Получается только 1,2,2,1;.. Знаю, что простейшее задание, я - первый курс.

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь сделать? Как именно "перевернуть"?

Comment: Отзеркалить)) То бишь, 1,2,3,5 в 5,3,2,1

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java

Comment: Тобишь Collections.reverse()

Comment: @entithat, https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/178988

Comment: @SantaMurphy, код надо вставлять в вопрос текстом, а не скриншотом.

Comment: @Qwertiy, давно хотел узнать об этом подробней, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что ты проходишь по всему массиву.

```
     1 2 3 4
i=0  i-----^
     4 2 3 1
i=1    i-^  
     4 3 2 1
i=2    ^-i  
     4 2 3 1
i=3  ^-----i
     1 2 3 4
```

А надо было остановиться на середине массива:

```
for (int i=0; i<a.length/2; ++i)
  меняем a[i] и a[a.length-1-i] местами
```

или вообще использовать две переменных

```
for (int i=0, j=a.length-1; i<j; ++i, --j)
  меняем a[i] и a[j] местами
```

Лично мне второй подход кажется более красивым.

PS: А для того, чтобы подобных вопросов не возникало, существует отладчик, который на каждом шаге покажет, чему равны значения переменных.

Comment: *фюдутпер* - забавно звучит:)

Comment: @entithat, да, раскладку зря переключил)))

Answer (score 1):

for(int i=0;i< array.length/2;i++){
 ...
}

Comment: Да, /2 уже добавила, но ответ теперь 1,2

Comment: Отлично работает ваш код, вы вероятно сверяетесь с выводом в цикле reverse операции, а не конечным результатом

Comment: public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] array = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
        
        for(int i=0;i< array.length;i++){
            System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
        }
        
        System.out.println();
        
        for(int i=0;i< array.length/2;i++){
         int tmp = array[i];
         array[i] = array[array.length-1-i];
         array[array.length-1-i] = tmp;
         
         
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i< array.length;i++){
            System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}